# Instant search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, search

What types of algorithms would work the quickest for a search of just what's being searched? I realize this is getting quite close to asking how Google-instant search works, but I'm no Algorithms expert and I've been becoming increasingly interested in them. Is a search like this done using suffix trees or something similar? I guess I'm just interested in querying little strings as opposed to lots of crawled data the way Google does.

Thanks much for any input!

Comment: You may also like reading Map-reduce paper by Google. http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html may be reverse index as well http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_index

Comment: All great reads by each answer and this comment... damn I think I set myself for more of a forum of answers... I'll read a bit more and try to pick one I like the most. This type of stuff has always baffled me and now I finally get some understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those types of queries you can store the data in a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) or a kind of Trie tree.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just for trying small set of strings, then of the [standard search algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) is a good place to start. Searching each character at a time and finding the common set of characters between two sets, is best accomplished using Dynamic programming technicals and one such example is finding [Longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem).

Answer (score 1):

Tree is fine, but you don't need to put your array in a multidimensional array.
Here is my way to do it with big arrays in JS.

You need to sort the array.

Jump to the middle of the array.
Loop:
If the array item is smaller then tosearch, jump to the middle of the upper half;
Else if the array item is bigger then tosearch, jump to the middle of the lower half;
else you found it. etc.

```
var maxstep=Math.abs((Math.log(0.5)-Math.log(array.length))/Math.log(2)-1);

function searchinterval(tosearch,array){
         var len=array.length,
             pos=range=len/2,
             index=Math.round(pos),
             maxstep=.49999;
         for(var i=0;i<=maxstep;i++){
              range/=2;
              if(tosearch<array[index]){
                pos-=range;
                }
              else if(tosearch>array[index]){
                pos+=range;
                }
              else{
                return index;
                //you found it
                }
              index=Math.round(pos);
              }
         return false;
         }
```

If tosearch not exists in the Array this function is slow. Means seven loops for an array length of 200  <strike>I'm not certain with the maximal number of steps or step size.</strike>

PS: Think I found out the maximum of steps:(thanks Maxima)

```
Log(0.5)-Log(array_length))/Log(2) -1);
```