# Multi-sorting a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var availableTags = [
    {value:"fruit",desc:"fruit",groupId:2,userId:4},
    {value:"aGan",desc:"normal user",groupId:4,userId:5},
    {value:"father's home ",desc:"normal user",groupId:2,userId:4}     

  ].sort(function(a, b) {  return a.groupId > b.groupId; });
```

This sorts by `groupId` field, but how do I to sort by `groupId` and `value`?

Comment: It might be useful for you to know that `a.groupId > b.groupId` may return incorrect results, depending on your browser. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9375788/989121

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the return statement to

```
return a.groupId > b.groupId || (a.groupId == b.groupId && a.value > b.value);
```

Comment: It's better to return -1, 0, 1 in the `.sort()` function callback.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
.sort(function (a, b) {
    var firstGroupId = a.groupId;
    var secondGroupId = b.groupId;

    return (firstGroupId === secondGroupId) ? a.value > b.value : firstGroupId > secondGroupId;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Copying my [recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9175783/989121)

```
cmp = function(a, b) {
    if (a > b) return +1;
    if (a < b) return -1;
    return 0;
}

array.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return cmp(a.groupId,b.groupId) || cmp(a.value,b.value)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript Multi-Criteria Sort**

If you want to sort by *groupId* and *value*, you can use the sort function that I've pasted below (JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oahxg4u3/6/). This sort function can also be used to sort by n-values, or by a single value.

Define:

```
function sortByCriteria(data, criteria) {
    return data.sort(function (a, b) {

        var i, iLen, aChain, bChain;

        i = 0;
        iLen = criteria.length;
        for (i; i < iLen; i++) {        
            aChain += a[criteria[i]];
            bChain += b[criteria[i]];
        }

        return aChain.localeCompare(bChain);
    });
}
```

Invoke:

```
var data = [
    {value:"fruit", desc:"fruit", groupId:2, userId:4},
    {value:"aGan", desc:"normal user", groupId:4, userId:5},
    {value:"father's home ", desc:"normal user", groupId:2, userId:4}
];
var criteria = ["groupId", "value"];

sortByCriteria(data, criteria);
```