# Wrong sort callback - results still correct

Tags: javascript, sorting

As generally known, [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback function is supposed to return -1, 0 or 1, depending on how its arguments compare. Despite this, I often see sort callbacks written in the following way:

```
someArray.sort(function(a, b) { return a > b })
```

Although this obviously doesn't conform the specs, since the callback only returns 0 or 1, it still seems to produce correct results:

```
a = []
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
a.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))

console.log(a.sort(function(a, b) { return a > b }))
```

Can anyone provide an example where the above callback function will cause an array to be sorted incorrectly? Array elements don't have to be numbers.

Comment: In which browser do you get correct results? I get (for example) `[30, 558, 558, 408, 316, 26, 112,...]` in Chrome, which already proofs that you should not use such a method. If you get correct results, then by coincidence.

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, indeed, Firefox seems to be more permissive in this regard. The above works in FF and fails in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the specific browser's sorting implementation, whether it uses the less-than comparison, and whether it autocasts sorting function's return value to int.

This fails in IE9, but works in Chrome:

```
"cadbe".split('').sort(function(a,b) { return a > b });
```

This works in IE9 and Chrome:

```
"cadbe".split('').sort();
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the case.