# Javascript sort array twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

If I have an array of locations like so:

```
["Roberts", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
["Adams", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
["Joes", "philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "30333"],
["Carls", "new york", "New York", "40415"]
```

Using Javascript or Jquery, How would I first sort them by state, then by name, so the resulting order would be:

```
["Adams", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
["Roberts", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
["Carls", "new york", "New York", "40415"],
["Joes", "philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "30333"]
```

Comment: The result list doesn't appear to be sorted by state.

Comment: The data doesn't appear to be in any JS data format.

Comment: What problem are you having? Reading whatever file the data is stored in? Parsing your custom data format? Finding the documentation for the Array sort method?

Comment: Um, that is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: Has been asked so many times... http://stackoverflow.com/q/16164078/989121

Comment: You may like to try this :<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374538/multi-sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we start with an actual array:

```
var orig = [
  ["Roberts", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
  ["Adams", "baltimore", "Maryland", "21212"],
  ["Joes", "philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "30333"],
  ["Carls", "new york", "New York", "40415"]
];
```

We can sort it like so:

```
var sorted = orig.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    // compare states
    if (a[2] < b[2])
      return -1;
    else if (a[2] > b[2])
      return 1;

    // states were equal, try names
    if (a[0] < b[0])
      return -1;
    else if (a[0] > b[0])
      return 1;

    return 0;
  }
);
```

which returns:

```
[
  ["Adams","baltimore","Maryland","21212"],
  ["Roberts","baltimore","Maryland","21212"],
  ["Carls","new york","New York","40415"],     
  ["Joes","philadelphia","Pennsylvania","30333"]
]
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/ADihk

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer (see at the end), but will need an explicit custom criteria:

""" compare(object1, object2)
if object1.state > object2.state then object1 is greater (1)
if object1.state < object2.state then object2 is greater (-1)
if object1.name > object2.name then object1 is greater (1)
if object1.name < object2.name then object2 is greater (-1)
objects are equal or, at least, not sortable by the criteria you exposed.
"""

[How to sort an array of objects with jquery or javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503900/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-jquery-or-javascript)

(note that "array" in array.sort refers your array of objects, and provided your object have actually the field names "name" and "state", since you did not actually specify them - actually they have no fields, so they are not objects nor arrays).